# Regular Expression or condition

Tags: sql-server, regex

Can we use one regular expression for these four conditions?

```
select * from ExceEnt where 
   FirstName Like @name+'[ ]%' 
or FirstName=@name 
or FirstName Like'%[ ]'+@name
or FirstName Like'%[ ]'+@name+'[ ]%'
```

Comment: Sometimes, it's better to put things in words. So, you want a match when `FirstName = @name`, or `@name` is one of the elements of `FirstName`, if it's split by spaces?

Comment: There's nothing built in to SQL Server for regex's. You can implement via CLR, if you [need to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Comment: No I want one regex instead of using four conditions

Comment: @NuwanSanjeewa, have you checked my suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

May be I didn't understand you completely but i am expecting that you need an expression that would match either exactly, a part of it, starts with or ends with the `data` you are requesting to search.

I would suggest you to look at **PATINDEX** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)) method to merge above four to appear as a single entity.

Check this example: (This can help you to figure out your issue)

```
--Drop table if table already exists 
if exists(select * from sys.tables where object_id=object_id('ExceEnt'))
drop table ExceEnt
GO

--Create table
create table ExceEnt
(
  FirstName varchar(200) NULL
)
GO

--Insert some data
insert into ExceEnt values('Never')
insert into ExceEnt values('Hopeless')
insert into ExceEnt values('NeverHopeless')
insert into ExceEnt values('As the name says NeverHopeless')
insert into ExceEnt values('Exclude others')
insert into ExceEnt values('Exclude this one too')

--Here use PATINDEX to find desired result
select * from ExceEnt where patindex('%Hopeless%',FirstName)>0
```

The above script generates the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like you [have already been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433544/regular-expression-or-condition#comment18363257_13433544), SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions natively and one possible solution would be to resort to CLR.

Alternatively, however, you could reduce your four conditions to only one like this:

```
…
WHERE ' ' + FirstName + ' ' LIKE '% ' + @name + ' %'
      -- or, if you prefer: LIKE '%[ ]' + @name + '[ ]%'
```

It is true that this condition would probably render your query non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), but if you use `LIKE '%whatever'` as your filter, your query becomes non-sargable anyway.